# Unnecessary Reduce terms?

Tags: equation-solving

Given the expression:

```
Simplify[Reduce[Exists[{x},a x^2+b x+ c==0],x,Reals]]
```

The answer comes out as:

```
(b==0 && ((c>0 && a<0)||(a>0 && c<0)))||(b!=0 && 4 a c<=b^2)||c==0
```

However, surely this is just the same as:

```
b^2-4ac >= 0
```

Since if a or c is 0 this is always true and this one statement covers all the cases.

So why doesn't it simplify to this? Or is there a way to make it simplify to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exists` and `ForAll` are qualifier statements and you can attempt to `Resolve` them to remove the qualifiers as follows:

```
qualifierStatement=Exists[x,a x^2+b x+c==0]
```

Now to resolve it under the real domain as follows:

```
resolvedStatement=Resolve[qualifierStatement,Reals]
```

Now to get your condition you need to ensure that the quadratic actually exist which is only true as long as `a!=0`, i.e. the highest term of power 2 exists. So we get the condition as follows:

```
conditionForQuadratic=Simplify[resolvedStatement,Assumptions->a!=0]
```

> 4 a c <= b^2

Note: using `Reduce` is not appropriate here since it has general equation and inequality solving algorithms which does more than just `Resolve` the qualifiers. `Reduce` expands and splits the conditions too much for `Simplify` to bring them together again!

Answer (score 3):

The first predicate is false for a->0, b->0, c->1:

```
(b==0 && ((c>0 && a<0)||(a>0 && c<0)))||(b!=0 && 4 a c<=b^2)||c==0 /. {a->0, b->0, c->1}
```

> False

The second predicate is true for this case:

```
b^2 - 4 a c >= 0 /. {a->0, b->0, c->1}
```

> True

Comment: Ah good point. Seems like its still long winded though.